# WPF triggering on multiple update sources

Tags: wpf, xaml, idataerrorinfo

Quick googling doesn't yield a viable duplicate for this.  I have what I hope is a pretty simple question about WPF error templates and/or the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of a Binding.  I'm kind of a WPF n00b so bear with me.

I can't post code per se (work-related), but here's the basic idea:

I have a standard set of a couple radio buttons in the same group.  I have a text box "attached" to one of them, in the sense that `TextBox.isEnabled` is databound to `rb.isChecked` of one of the radio buttons.

The text box validates on data error, using `PropertyChanged` triggers.  When an error occurs, it draws a red box around itself.

The problem I'm having is that "empty text box" is an error condition if and only if the radio button has enabled the text box.  I need the error box to go away when I select the other radio button, but it doesn't.

My first thought was to try to tie something in the error template to `(HasError && IsEnabled)` but I can't see a clear way to do that.

I think that maybe triggering the `TextBox` (via `UpdateSourceTrigger`) on the `FocusLost` event in addition to `PropertyChanged` might work.  Is there a way to do that?

Alternate solutions are welcome, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation will re-run whenever `PropertyChanged` is called. This means that you can force revalidation by raising the `PropertyChanged` event for the `TextBox` binding.

Since you need to revalidate when the `RadioButton.IsChecked` changes you can raise `PropertyChanged` for the property that the `TextBox` is bound to on the setter for the property that the `RadioButton` is bound to.

Example:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public bool MyRadioButtonIsSelected
    {
       get { return myRadioButtonIsSelectedBacking; }
       set
       {
           myRadioButtonIsSelectedBacking= value;
           OnPropertyChanged("MyRadioButtonIsSelected");

           // Force revalidation of MyTextBoxValue
           OnPropertyChanged("MyTextBoxValue");
       }
    }

    public string MyTextBoxValue
    {
       get { return myTextBoxPropertyBackingField; }
       set
       {
           myTextBoxPropertyBackingField= value;
           OnPropertyChanged("MyTextBoxValue");
       }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<RadioButton
    Content="My Radio Button"
    IsChecked="{Binding MyRadioButtonIsSelected}" />
<TextBox 
    IsEnabled="{Binding MyRadioButtonIsSelected}"
    Text="{Binding MyTextBoxValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```